# How to add a single value to all keys of a Guava multimap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, multimap

How to add one single value to all keys of a Guava multimap in Java?

For example, I create a multimap with an ID and a String:

```
    final Multimap<Integer, String> myMap = HashMultimap.create();
      myMap.put(0, "snake");
      myMap.put(1, "crocodile");
      myMap.put(2, "turtle");
```

Now I want to add one entry "reptile" to all keys. After that, my map should look like this:

```
    {
        0=[snake, reptile], 
        1=[crocodile, reptile], 
        2=[turtle, reptile]
    }
```

Comment: You might find the [Multimap.keySet()](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#keySet--) method helpful. See also [How do I ask about homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: I wonder a little bit about the procedure. Someone changed my question from "Is there an easy way...?" to "How to...?". The latter wording suggests that I had no idea how to implement that. As a result, I am recommended to do my homework by myself :D
But thanks for the support :)

Comment: My suggestion was based on content and omission, not on the edits. More detail is available at the link above.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. The problem was, I did not post my current solution. I will do that in the future. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
myMap.asMap().values().forEach(v -> v.add("reptile"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. In this case I iterate through the map. That's ok. But on [link](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) I found:

`putAll(K key, Iterable<? extends V> values)`
what stores a key-value pair in this multimap for each of values, all using the same key.

I thought there was a similar solution for my case. Ok, I'll do it in your way. Many Thanks :)